# Using GIT to keep track of a particular folder/file in the Linux tree

Tags: git

I want to keep track of a particular feature of the Linux kernel using GIT.
For example say ext3 file system or the arm architecture dependent code. So, I want to configure GIT such that it will show me all the commits and diffs which are concerned with ext3 or ARM.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log your/path?
```

To see patches, use `git log -p`.

Comment: Thanks!! Can we also give the time span or the version number with the git log? Suppose I want to know the modifications for arch/arm after the kernel version 2.6.30 then what would be the command. Also, where can i get all the options for using git log?

Comment: @Ashish - this'll help you out a ton: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/